# Creating holes in 2D Unity images

Tags: unity-game-engine

tell me,I'm wondering about working with 2D in Unity ,how to make a hole in the image in 2D,what method to use.Example in this game: http://www.game-game.com.ua/184002/ Similar topics address a different issue,where they discuss ways to make some of the images transparent. One of the methods that I see immediately is 2 image 1 is drawn at the bottom,then the ball is drawn,and then the repeating object is drawn again to overlap the ball.Thank You in advance.
Interested in how exactly to do the same (example from the game above)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the SpriteMask tool

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html

or just divide the hole ring into 2 images 1 in Background and one in layer on top of the ball
so it hides the ball if falling behind it